# Always fill TextView with provided text

Tags: android, text, textview, scale

I have a textview that has a fill_parent width and a set height.  Is it possible to have the text scale to fit the textview automatically if the text is larger than the textview?  I don't want it to wrap and i don't want the textview to expand.  For example, one word would scale to the maximum height of the textview, but 10 words would scale smaller so that it would all fit into the textview.  I hope I said it clearly...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can work this out by getting the [TextPaint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html) from the `TextView` (`getPaint()`).

You would need to use `getTextWidths`, `getTextBounds` and other methods available in the `Paint` api.

Comment: Ugh...I was hoping I missed a built-in feature.  But, this get me going in the right direction.  Thanks